# Python Flask webapp simple proxy configuration to enable SSL/HTTPS with Apache

Tags: python, apache, web-applications, proxy, flask

I have a working webapp based on Python, Flask. (configured to work on http:// host:port)

I need to get it to work with https. I was given an Apache proxy - which redirects all requests in such  fashion:

(Apache)    https:// host/myApp --> http:// host:port (my Flask based app). Where ***host:port*** is the standard configuration where my app was working fine.

I am able to reach the service and index page. However, there is an issue with accessing all static content, which was requested vi **url_for** method (like *ico, images* etc.).

Can you point me to any resources/info? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of issue are you seeing? 404 error? What happens if you manually type the correct url of a static resource adding the https, removing the s? Which application is *actually* serving the static files, Apache or your web app (it can be both, but ideally is Apache).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We add a line in httpd.conf that handles /static/ instead of proxying it to gunicorn:

```
<VirtualHost oursite.com>

  # Tells apache where /static/ should go
  Alias /static/ /full/path/to/flask/app/static/

  # Proxy everything to gunicorn EXCEPT /static and favicon.ico
  ProxyPass /favicon.ico !
  ProxyPass /static !
  ProxyPass / http://gunicorn.oursite.com:4242/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://gunicorn.oursite.com:4242/

</VirtualHost>
```

This works because we have gunicorn and apache running on the same box, which may or may not work for you. You might have to copy the static files to the apache host as part of your site deployment.

There's probably a better way to do it, but it works for us.