# How do you setup Python with virtualenv locally and on a real Linode server (or similar)?

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, pycharm, linode

Using PyCharm on Windows and would like to gain a better understanding of how to setup my local environment so that it translates cleanly as possible to my servers on Linode (or any other Linux box for that matter).

I have a physical drive set aside for development work.  In my case this is drive `Z:`.

I will typically create one directory per project.  A project being defined as an entire website.

I have currently also opted to have a directory, `Z:\virtualenv`, where I create my virtual environments. One per project.  I suppose multiple projects could share the same virtualenv but I am not sure if this is smart for either development or production.

I've considered the idea of having the per-project virtualenv live inside it's corresponding project.  This appeals to me because then each project would be monolithic.  For example, if we are talking about Flask application under PyCharm:

```
d    z:\flask_app
d         .git
d         .idea
d         static
d         templates
d         virtualenv
          main.py
```

How, then, do you setup the production server given the above?

Let's assume one is using a single machine to host more than one site through virtual hosting, this being one of them:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin you@example.com

  ServerName   example.com
  ServerAlias  example.com *.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public_html
  ErrorLog     /var/www/example/logs/access.log
  CustomLog    /var/www/example/logs/error.log combined

  <Directory   /var/www/example>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Do I setup virtualenv at the global server level?  I think that's a global "yes".  It couldn't work any other way.  I don't think.

OK, that does mean that the entire file structure under

```
z:\flask_app
```

can now be FTP'd into

```
/var/www/example/public_html
```

and the site is good to go?

I understand that db server, db's, tables, etc. need to be setup on the production machine to match.  I am simply focusing on Python on the transition of Python with virtualenv from a desktop development environment to an external Linux production box.

I think I have to use virtualenv at the server root level to also enable that virtual environment, right?  This is where I am a bit fuzzy about things.  Most tutorials I've come across cover your local development environment extensively but rarely go into the transition of projects to production servers, their setup and ongoing relationship to the development setup.

I will be using a virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to sort this out as I move forward.

I've also considered using 14.04 Desktop for development on a VM in order to have matched environments and get off Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) A 14.04 Desktop VM just to muck around in and get things right before transferring to scripts and the command line for your server is a great idea.

2) You may happen to love the [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) tool/project. It maps almost exactly to your current workflow, but with some handy conveniences (its whole point). It essentially hosts a central folder of virtualenvs to different names (/ folders). Its most handy commands are `mkproject` (create a new folder and virtualenv of the same name) and `workon` (activate the project of that name).

3) Fortunately given 14.04 isn't too old, it has quite a recent virtualenv already present in its packages, `python-virtualenv` (1.11.4). I would install this and then use it to create environments on your server to run python projects under, as you suggest.

> OK, that does mean that the entire file structure under ... can now be FTP'd into ... and the site is good to go?

No, because you'd be trying to transfer a virtualenv created for a Python on a Windows machine and hoping it would work under a Python on Linux/Ubuntu.

4) To keep a managed list of packages each project needs installed, list them in a [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#requirements-files). Then with a new virtualenv active, you can simply run `pip install -r requirements.txt` and all the needed packages will be installed for it.

5) For running your apps under the one server, I would suggest running a local WSGI server like [Chaussette](http://chaussette.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (perhaps under [Circus](http://circus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) or [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that hosts your python WSGI app under a local port / unix socket; then configure Apache or Nginx to reverse proxy all needed dynamic traffic to that server (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838302/python-flask-webapp-simple-proxy-configuration-to-enable-ssl-https-with-apache) as an example).

6) Some rudimentary bash scripting know-how can help a lot if you have things repeatably bootstrap-able :) If it gets even more complicated, you can use a managed configuration product like [Salt](http://www.saltstack.com/community/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I will be using Ansible for deployment automation.  I really like the approach you suggested with a `requirements.txt` file. Are you suggesting this could or should be kept in the project tree, maintained manually and source controlled with Git?

Comment: Yes, that would work fine. It's quite normal to keep a `requirements.txt` under source control.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this: your Git repository should contain the source code, data files and other files relating to developing that project. It shouldn't contain the virtualenv as that is a mix of executables (Python, pip), header files and dependencies installed from various sources. It should be possible to wipe a virtualenv and rebuild it without much hassle.

Although you could have source and virtualenv in the same directory, you'd need to update your `.gitignore` file anyway which indicates that it makes sense to locate all virtualenvs elsewhere. It's not a matter of FTP'ing a whole directory into another: you should separate the notion of updating code from the notion of setting up a virtualenv (which may have different packages installed than your development machine).

For example, you would be developing on a Windows machine and deploy to a Linux machine which could lead to different packages being used. So it's important to separate "project source code" from "dependencies and configuration needed to run".

Likewise, on the production servers you can designate one location for your virtualenvs and all projects (which have their code installed somewhere, in a directory structure of your choice) would activate the virtualenv and then run. There isn't really a wrong or right way to do things, as long as each process has sufficient permissions to do its thing.

Depending on how much automating you wish to put into the deployment, you should consider at least automating a little bit to ensure it works properly. It comes down to setting up the directory structure, permissions, checking out code from git, setting up a virtualenv, installing dependencies and any other remaining configuration to make things work. You can do these tasks with Ansible, for example.

In general it's better not to think of your application as one monolithic thing because things can move to other locations as time goes on. Static files? They may need to go to a content-delivery network someday. Database installation? May need to be moved to another machine someday. And so on.

Comment: Yes, I'll be using Ansible.  The Windows-vs-Linux issue is why I've been wondering if I should simply setup a Linux server in the office (virtual or a real box on the network) to match the production server installation.  If that's the case then one could probably simply FTP virtualenvs to the production server.  There's probably a little manual work to let the production virtualenv know of the existence of a new virtualenv, right?